# Azure Data Factory json dataset missing property in typeProperties

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am creating a dataset from json-formatted data in an Azure Data Factory (v1). When using the following code, I get a `Property expected` error with the infotext `Property specific to this data set type` on the `typeProperties` object. From what I can see, I am using the same properties as in the [example docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#json-format). What property am I missing?

Dataset definition:

```
{
    "name": "JsonDataSetData",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "linkedServiceName": "TestAzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "timestamp",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "value",
                "type": "Double"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "folderPath": "root_folder/sub_folder",
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "setOfObjects",
                "jsonPathDefinition": {
                    "spid": "$.timestamp",
                    "value": "$.value"
                }
            },
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding encodingName and nestingSeparator with the default values? The documentation has mistakes sometimes and a property that is documented as not required might be giving you this error.